# running pre and post deployment scripts in Visual Studio 2017 data tools (SSIS)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS project created in VS 2017.
It is in the project model.

I have a number of tsql scripts i want to execute as part of the deployment. I cannot find anywhere in the project to add additional deployment scripts.

Is it even possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "execute as part of the deployment"?   What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: i may want to execute an sql script to reset some values, or i may want to run a bat file or even an exe, either before or after a deployment of the ssis project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible to include extraneous scripts or executables to be automatically executed when you deploy an SSIS project.  They have to be executed separately.